# grub bootloader failed to install error when trying to install Ubuntu or Lubuntu - tried to reinstall grub but didn't work

Tags: grub2, system-installation, bootloader

I've unsuccessfully been trying to install Ubuntu or Lubuntu for a couple of weekends now. The installation seems to go fine until the end, when I get the "grub bootloader failed to install" error. I dug through the forums and tried all kinds of things, such as re-installing grub, but nothing worked.

Some background info:

- I did disable securable boot.
- The laptop formally had Windows 10 on it.
- I changed the hard disk (since I was planning to upgrade anyway), but this didn't make a difference.
- Here is the boot info https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/dt2RZgtT5Y/ Unfortunately, this doesn't tell me very much, so I hope someone else can tell me what's wrong!

Comment: Welcome to AskUbuntu. Your hard drive (internal) is encrypted therefore the Ubuntu Installer can not do anything about it. First thing you should do is to open bios setting and disable the encryption.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I didn't find anything about disk encryption in the BIOS. (The closest thing I found was the TMP settings, which shouldn't make a difference, right?) But I think the reason it is encrypted is from the half-finished L(ubuntu) installs, where I chose disk encryption. That's why I thought this shouldn't be a problem, right?

Comment: Reading log you provided line number 190 to the end, the encryption had some errors and a bootloader was not found. Then you should try normal primary partition to do it. The encryption itself should not be a problem but later on when we look the problem outside of the OS, using system rescue CD or such things, not able to do anything about it. I assume you are not a banker to use this machine. LVM sometimes has problems, why not the encrypted partitions have a lot of them? https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/552915/mount-fail-unknown-filesystem-type-crypto-luks

Comment: I re-formatted the partition to EXT4, then tried re-installing without selecting encryption or LVS, but I'm getting the same error...

Comment: Erase entire disk and create a new partition table, that would work.

Comment: It finally worked, thanks for pointing me in the right direction! Wiped and formatted the disk, tried to re-install grub, etc.. The first couple of attempts to install Ubuntu still failed for the same reason, but eventually it did. Not sure what did the trick, but for the attempt that finally worked, I had switched the computer to boot from BIOS rather than UEFI (and partitioned and formatted the disc accordingly, following the suggestions from https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/10/partitioning-hard-disk-drives-for-bios-mbr-bios-gpt-and-uefi-gpt-in-linux/ (bios-gpt option 1))...

Comment: With newer UEFI based hardware generally better to install in UEFI boot mode. But then you have to have an ESP - efi system partition and gpt partitioning. If installing in 35 year old BIOS boot configuration on newer gpt partitioning you need a 1 or 2MB unformatted bios_grub partition. Only use old MBR partitioning if you must have Windows in BIOS boot mode on drive. Advantages to gpt over MBR and UEFI over BIOS boot.

Answer (score 0):

You first need to find out which device your harddisk is.
Assuming that you have only one harddisk in your machine, then
your harddisk is /dev/sda  - but for safety look after in - for example -
gparted program. Start gparted and there you can see, if your harddisk is
/dev/sda or /dev/sdb (normally the DVD-drive is /dev/sda - if you have one).

In case of sda as harddisk - you then can type in terminal :

> sudo grub-install --force /dev/your-harddisk

This can look like:

> sudo grub-install --force /dev/sda
>
> sudo update-grub2

This should work. Please let me know, if this worked out for you.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Unfortunately, this didn't work, I'm getting the following error: "grub-install: error: failed to get canonical path of '\cow'". 

I googled that error message, and figured out I may have to do some remapping. I tried the following suggestions:

`sudo mount /dev/sda1/ /mnt/boot`

(sda1 is the partition where boot is located, according to gpart.) But I got the following error: "mount: mnt/boot: mount point does not exist."

Comment: Also tried the following suggestion:
`sudo apt-get update;
sudo apt-get install grub`
However, I get the following error: "package grub is not available, but is referred to by another package. This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or is only available from another source. However, the following packages replace it: grub2-common, grub-efi--ia32, grub-efi-amd64". 

Any ideas what else I can try?

Comment: @ThomasLoeber - grub2-packages are installed - right ? - command grub-install is settled ? - then use command in terminal : update-grub - sorry, for my late answer.

Comment: As far as I remember, I did have grub2 installed. I finally figured it out, I'll add my solution as an answer (it was in a comment).

Answer (score 0):

It's finally working, I tried a bunch of things, not sure what exactly finally did the trick: Wiped and formatted the disk, tried to re-install grub, etc.. The first couple of attempts to install Ubuntu still failed for the same reason, but eventually it did. Not sure what did the trick, but for the attempt that finally worked, I had switched the computer to boot from BIOS rather than UEFI (and partitioned and formatted the disc accordingly, following the suggestions from https://fitzcarraldoblog.wordpress.com/2017/02/10/partitioning-hard-disk-drives-for-bios-mbr-bios-gpt-and-uefi-gpt-in-linux/ (bios-gpt option 1))... [Moved this from comment to answer.]